# JBoss 4.2.3.GA documentation

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I have been required to implement a web application that will be deployed on JBoss 4.2.3.GA. I have never worked before with such old technology (I finished my studies last month) and I can't find any documentation.

Could someone tell me about online documentation? Currently I have no idea if I can use JSF or other related JEE technologies. Can anyone explain which versions of the Servlet API, JSP and JSF should I use and how to get and deploy them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss 4.2.3.GA is very old (from 2007) and J2EE 1.4.

JSF was added with Java EE 5 -> JBoss 5

Documentation can be found here:
http://narayana.jboss.org/documentation/4_2_3_GA

Comment: Thank you, now that I know that it follows the J2EE 1.4 spec I can find more documentation ;)